# Scaling one object to the exact size of another

Tags: mesh, transforms, baking

I would like the pink object(high poly mesh) to have the same, scale, size, and location as the green object (low poly mesh) in the pic below this so I can bake the high poly mesh to the low poly one.

How can I do it pls?

[image]

Comment: To use the same size use Dimension values seen in Side panel. To match Scale than Apply Scale for both. To match Location you would have to move Origin of both objects at the same place in edit mode, like Snap Origin to a Vertex, or try "Origin to Geometry" there is a chance it will match for lowres-hires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy:
Select the object you want to adjust the scale (rotation,position the same way)
Shiftclick then the object of which you want the scaling to be transfered. then go to the item-tab, right-click on scale and choose "copy all to selected" to transfer x-y-z-scaling or "copy single to selected" to transfer the scaling of the direction your mousecursor was hovering.

[image]

This also works in several other input areas of blender!